# JPanel for GUI Application

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, jscrollpane

So im teaching myself Java and ran into a bit of a stall. For one of the exercises, here is the instructions which I can't get my head around. Any help with explanation would be appreciated. Here is my attempt with the parts I am having trouble with.

```
import java.awt.Dimension;  
import java.awt.GridLayout;  
import javax.swing.JButton;  
import javax.swing.JPanel;  
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;  
import javax.swing.JTextArea;  

public class ButtonPanel extends JPanel {


    public ButtonPanel(JButton[] buttons, JTextArea textArea) {
        //TODO: Create a sub-panel with a 4 row, 3 column GridLayout

        setLayout(new GridLayout(4,3)); //Layout of subPanel1

        JButton b1 = new JButton ("A");
        JButton b2 = new JButton ("B");
        JButton b3 = new JButton ("C");
        JButton b4 = new JButton ("1");
        JButton b5 = new JButton ("2");
        JButton b6 = new JButton ("3");
        JButton b7 = new JButton ("X");
        JButton b8 = new JButton ("Y");
        JButton b9 = new JButton ("Z");

        add(b1);
        add(b2);
        add(b3);
        add(b4);
        add(b4);
        add(b5);

        //TODO: Populate the grid with buttons

        //TODO: Add the grid panel to this panel

        //TODO: Create a JScrollPane containing textArea

        JButton cr = new JButton();

        //TODO: Set the preferred size of the scroll pane to 80x120
        setPreferredSize (new Dimension(80, 120));

        //TODO: Add the scroll pane to this panel

    }


}
```

Comment: 5min of research will clear all your doubts

Comment: Create a new instance of JPanel, add the buttons to this panel, add this panel to the parent pane

Comment: @MadProgrammer I am struggling with this a bit. So can I add everything I need within one method as I have labeled above or would I need a different method everywhere I have written TODO?

Answer (score 1):

This is a rudimentary concept.

To add a component to a container, you need to

1. Create the container
2. Apply a layout manager to that container
3. Add components to that container
4. Add the container to a parent container that is attached (in some way) to a top level container

For example

```
public void ButtonPanel(JButton[] buttons, JTextArea textArea) {
    //TODO: Create a sub-panel with a 4 row, 3 column GridLayout

    JPanel buttonPanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(4,3)); //Layout of subPanel1

    JButton b1 = new JButton ("A");
    JButton b2 = new JButton ("B");
    JButton b3 = new JButton ("C");
    JButton b4 = new JButton ("1");
    JButton b5 = new JButton ("2");
    JButton b6 = new JButton ("3");
    JButton b7 = new JButton ("X");
    JButton b8 = new JButton ("Y");
    JButton b9 = new JButton ("Z");

    buttonPanel.add(b1);
    buttonPanel.add(b2);
    buttonPanel.add(b3);
    buttonPanel.add(b4);
    buttonPanel.add(b4);
    buttonPanel.add(b5);

    //TODO: Populate the grid with buttons

    //TODO: Add the grid panel to this panel

    //TODO: Create a JScrollPane containing textArea

    JButton cr = new JButton();

    //TODO: Set the preferred size of the scroll pane to 80x120
    // This is a bad idea
    setPreferredSize (new Dimension(80, 120));

    //TODO: Add the scroll pane to this panel

}
```

Take the time to read through and understand [Creating a UI with Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/)